# ¿Cómo adaptar un icono png a un menú responsive css?

Tags: html, html5, css, css3

Tengo un error en adaptar un icono png a un menú responsive, al cambiar el tamaño del navegador o al hacer la pantalla más pequeña el número de contacto salta de su ubicación. En cambio el texto en vez de saltar de su ubicación este se encima uno tras otro. ¿Cómo lograr el mismo efecto o el mismo estilo responsive con el icono png?.

Es decir que el icono también se encima uno tras otro, para evitar que el número de contacto salte de su ubicación.

Aquí el código completo y la demostración en ejecución:  https://jsfiddle.net/e5t94cm7/ Si pueden observar al hacer la pantalla del navegador más pequeña el número de contacto salta de su ubicación.

Estilo **css**

```
a {
  color: #777;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
  color: #515151;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.icon-phone:before {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background-image:url(http://www.imyshop.tk/font/icon/icon-phone.png);
  background-size:cover;
}

.icon-phone {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    /*margin-right: -1px;*/
    padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  height: 40px;
}

nav ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 16.6667%; /* fallback for non-calc() browsers */
  width: calc(100% / 5);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav ul li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #616161;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Menú **html**

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><i class="icon-phone"></i><a href="tel:+02222222">02222222</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Existe alguna forma de lograrlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El "problema" es que la imagen del teléfono se pone a través de un `<i>` (de manera similar a como lo hace Font Awesome o Bootstrap), y ese elemento ocupa un espacio que hace que el número de teléfono salte cuando las pantallas se hacen más pequeñas.

Una posibilidad para evitar que eso ocurra sería agregar la imagen de fondo a la propia celda que contiene el teléfono (y eliminar el elemento `<i>`). Algo como esto:

```css
a {
  color: #777;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
  color: #515151;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.icon-phone {
  background-image:url(http://www.imyshop.tk/font/icon/icon-phone.png);
  background-position:left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  height: 40px;
}

nav ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 16.6667%; /* fallback for non-calc() browsers */
  width: calc(100% / 5);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav ul li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #616161;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="icon-phone"><a href="home.html">02222222</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Puedes cambiar el valor de `background-size` y `background-position` para que se ajuste mejor a lo que buscas (inicialmente había puesto `contain` y `top left`, pero creo que ahora se ve mejor).

Comment: perfecto amigo es una buena opción, esto solucionaría todo gracias amigo. Entonces la etiqueta `li` se descartaría verdad no existe solución para aquella etiqueta verdad.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres? Eliminé la etiqueta `i` no la `li`

Comment: Olvídalo amigo gracias por ayudarme.

Comment: Podrías poner `position:relative` al li, y poner `position:absolute` al i si quieres mantener la misma estructura

Comment: Ok amigo muchísimas gracias, las dos opciones que me haz dado me ayudaran de mucho para futuro diseños. Te lo agradezco mucho.

Answer (score 0):

A `.icon-phone:before {` ponle un `display:inline;` y arreglado

Lo único que hago es que le doy la misma propiedad `display` que el resto de elementos hermanos

Comment: Sería de agradecer, dado que a este tipo de preguntas suele acudir gente con los mismos problemas, que te explayes un poco más y a ser posible, pongas un ejemplo un poco más completo. Puede parecer una tontería, pero si a esta pregunta llega alguien más bien novato puede tener ciertos problemas a la hora de aplicar lo que dices.

Answer (score 0):

Me resulta curioso que uses `<i>` para agregar iconos tal como hacen Font Awesome, usada por Sencha, y Glyphicons, la librería que usa Bootstrap. Si es así sólo tienes que añadir a la `<i>` las clases de cada librería de glyphos, para [Font Awesome](https://origin.fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=phone) sería `<i class="fas fa-phone">` mientras que para [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/) sería `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone">`.

Usar glyphos es mucho más efectivo que usar PNG, ya que, al ser texto te permite modificar color y tamaño por CSS fácilmente.

En cuanto a tu problema del cambio de línea es debido a que por falta de espacio el texto no cabe en una única línea, pero lo puedes forzar así:

```
.icon-phone {
    white-pace: nowrap
}
```

Sin embargo, esto provocará que se superponga con sus elementos hermanos.

Como comentas que es un diseño responsive, la solución a ese problema es utilizar una mediaquery para controlar la vista para un nuevo dispositivo de menor tamaño. Tanto Bootstrap como Sencha disponen de soluciones para esos casos. Si las estás usando te recomiendo eches un vistazo a la documentación.

Si no es así entonces aquí te dejo una pequeña simulación:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  var clickBurguer = function() {
  //Ocultamos o mostramos el menú asociado a la hamburguesa que ha sido pulsada
   $('.hamburguer').on('click', function(){
     var thisMenu = $(this).siblings('.menu');
     $(thisMenu).toggleClass('hidden'); //Cambiamos entre los estados visible y oculto
   });
  }
  clickBurguer(); //Inicializamos clickBurguer
});
```

```css
a {
  color: #777;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
  color: #515151;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.icon-phone {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.icon-phone:before {
  content: url(https://fakeimg.pl/16x16/);
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

nav ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 16.6667%; /* fallback for non-calc() browsers */
  width: calc(100% / 5);
  padding: 10px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #616161;
}
.hamburguer {
 display: none;
 }
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
  nav ul li {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  }
.hamburguer {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 3.125rem;
 height: 3.125rem;
 background: transparent url(https://fakeimg.pl/16x16/) no-repeat center center;
 border: 0;
 }
 .hidden {
  display: none;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <button type="button" class="hamburguer"></button>
  <ul class="menu hidden">
    <li class="icon-phone"><a href="home.html">02222222</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Este código sólo es un pequeño ejemplo dentro de un sniped limitado por el ancho de su contenedor. Para ver cómo hacer un menú responsive correctamente mejor consultar la [fuente](http://www.elcssar.com/responsive/menu-responsive-css).